# Should a tag exist for multiple questions about a specific court case?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have several questions about *[Oracle America, Inc. v. Google, Inc.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_America,_Inc._v._Google,_Inc.)*:

- [What exactly are the "Java APIs" that were under debate in Oracle America, Inc. v. Google, Inc.?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/9528/1165)
- [In Oracle America v. Google, what was the District Court jury's rationale behind its "fair use" finding?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/9510/1165)
- [Oracle vs Google: Can Oracle sue any company who is using Java and making profit?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/9360/1165)

There are also several questions about the impact of this court case:

- [Is it legal to rewrite a Java (OpenJDK) library into another programming language under GPL?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/8213/1165)
- [Is WINE illegal?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/4377/1165)
- [Are court rulings Retroactive?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/5997/1165) (used as an example)

Right now, the these questions are under general tags like [copyright](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copyright), even though they are really about the ruling of this specific case, and less about the general topic of copyright.

Since we have several questions about this particular court case (three of them are most definitely, the rest may be debateable), would it make sense to create a tag for the specific case, such as [oracle-v-google](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle-v-google)?

I could see single tags being used for other prominent court cases in the future, should questions be asked about them (e.g. [brown-v-board-of-education](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brown-v-board-of-education)).